# How to make a switch case in Swift to continue to the next case condition?

Tags: switch-statement, swift

In *Swift*, once a switch condition is reached it does implicitly "break" and get out of the switch case. In other terms it does not continues to the next condition one. How to achieve the regular behaviour as in *C*, *C++*, *java*, *javascript* etc… ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Taken from the [Apple Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_153):

*If you really need C-style fallthrough behavior, you can opt in to this behavior on a case-by-case basis with the **fallthrough** keyword. The example below uses fallthrough to create a textual description of a number:*

```
let integerToDescribe = 5
var description = "The number \(integerToDescribe) is"
switch integerToDescribe {
case 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19:
    description += " a prime number, and also"
    fallthrough // explicitly tells to continue to the default case
default:
    description += " an integer."
}
println(description)
// prints "The number 5 is a prime number, and also an integer."
```

Comment: So weird that this exists. Thanks but I don't think this should be used.